# Pre-populate a SharePoint new item form

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I need to pre-populate a list form (the add new item form for a list)
with some details (the logged in users name and email address)

how can i do it?

Answer (score 4):

2 options:

- create your own custom form with controls.
- create a tiny weppart that does nothing else but render user info in javascript. then use jquery to get that info in the fields in the form.

Comment: where would i get the users info from? Is it easily accessible within sharepoint then?

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the same thing, trying to populate a people picker field.

I'm not done yet, but I was able to implement a CEWP (Custom Editor Web Part) in the form, adding:

```
?PageView=Shared&ToolPaneView=2
```

at the end of the URL of the new form. Example:

```
NewForm.aspx?RootFolder=.....default.aspx**&PageView=Shared&ToolPaneView=2**
```

After that,I put JQuery in the Web Part content, until now I trying to implement SPFF, but is kinda hard because there are not too many examples... by the time I'm done I would be pleased to help you